# import from xml into jtable

Tags: java, xml, jtable

I have written a code that can save data into xml. NOW I want to use that stored xml and import its data in a table I have in the form. the problem is: the code is with no error but the table is not field with the xml data :( 
here is my code:

```
  private void jPanel4ComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                       
      // TODO add your handling code here:
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try{
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("D:\\test.xml");

    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList nodelist1 = root.getElementsByTagName("FrameDefinitionSection");

    String[] st= new String[4];

    for(int i=0;i<nodelist1.getLength();i++)
    {
        Node node=nodelist1.item(i);
        st[0]= node.getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
        st[1]= node.getChildNodes().item(3).getTextContent();
        st[2]= node.getChildNodes().item(5).getTextContent();
        st[3]= node.getChildNodes().item(7).getTextContent();
        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(st);
    }



    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.print("error");
    }
}
```

and here is my xml file : 
the table should show the nodes in this xml into fields of table but it does not work ! :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<FrameDefinitionSection>
<FrameNameAndElements>
<FrameName>here is the frame's name</FrameName>
<FrameElements>its element</FrameElements>
</FrameNameAndElements>
<FrameDefinition>
<Definition>the definition of the frame</Definition>
</FrameDefinition>
<FrameExampleSentences>
<ExampleSentences>its example as well</ExampleSentences>
</FrameExampleSentences>
</FrameDefinitionSection>
```

Comment: `catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.print("error");
    }`  change that to `catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }` then we might know why *"..it does not work !"*

Comment: no it did not help. its sth wrong with                                    NodeList nodelist1 = root.getElementsByTagName("FrameDefinitionSection");

    String[] st= new String[4];

    for(int i=0;i<nodelist1.getLength();i++)
    {
        Node node=nodelist1.item(i);
        st[0]= node.getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
        st[1]= node.getChildNodes().item(3).getTextContent();
        st[2]= node.getChildNodes().item(5).getTextContent();
        st[3]= node.getChildNodes().item(7).getTextContent();
        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(st);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You search for nodes FrameDefinitionSection-Tags under the Root-Node, but you have to search for FrameNameAndElements-Tags
2. getElementsByTagName will find sub-sub-sub-tags too.

You better use this:

```
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("D:\\test.xml");

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList nodelist1 =
                root.getChildNodes();

        String[] st = new String[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < nodelist1.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = nodelist1.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == node.ENTITY_NODE) {
                st[0] = node.getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
                st[1] = node.getChildNodes().item(3).getTextContent();
                st[2] = node.getChildNodes().item(5).getTextContent();
                st[3] = node.getChildNodes().item(7).getTextContent();
                ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(st);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I tried changing the code, but it builds successfully, but the table is empty!!

Comment: The only way out is to debug. What a IDE do you use?

Comment: Wait, your code prints "error" but Andrew Thompson's code doest print anything? Seriously, you have to fix your basic Environment first.

Comment: Peter:  IDE6.8 .......... it prints "error" because of System.out.print("error");    but Andrew's code is  ex.printStackTrace();      thats why

Comment: Is there no Output? Did you debug the Code? For your Information: printStackTrace uses System.out.print too, but it gives more informations than "error" :) .

Comment: Have no FileObject for C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar
Have no FileObject for C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\classes

Comment: Great, i think this is a problem of your debugger. What is your IDE?

Comment: There was sth wrong with xml file. I added a new node at the beggining and it works now. Thanks all

Comment: SunnY? Would you like to accept any one of theese answers please?

Answer (score 0):

if you write like following, nodelist1 is null.

```
 NodeList nodelist1 = root.getElementsByTagName("FrameDefinitionSection");
```

So you need to change like this ,

```
  NodeList nodelist1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("FrameDefinitionSection");
```

Comment: Hi 9ine, i guess he'd like to have a list of FrameExampleSentences. Because FrameDefinitionSection already stored in root ;)